# Which one is better in Samosa dough,Ghee or Oil?

Tags: frying, ingredient-selection

Which one is better in samosa dough, ghee or oil? some people use ghee in dough of samosa and some people use oil.Is there any difference in taste and texture of samosa while using ghee or oil in dough after frying it?

Comment: There are sects in India that are vegan .... so they'd never use ghee

Comment: Some people also use vegetable ghee, which is basically flavoured canola oil.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the oil otherwise I would recommend ghee, it has a nice nutty aroma and it’s more stable with high heat compared to other oils such as vegetable, canaola and olive oil. The only oil I would use, would be coconut oil.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To make a good pastry for Samosa, ghee is better. But for the best result you can use Vanaspati ghee, which is called as Dalda. It is widely used for making perfect crisp samosa. It is a vegetable ghee.
You can check the recipe for Samosa where Dalda, is used to make crispy samosa.
https://www.hassanchef.com/2019/09/samosa-how-to-make-samosa-recipe.html